# Is it possible to create new cordova based ipad application in xcode

Tags: iphone, ipad, cordova, xcode4.2

I'm using Xcode 4.2 for ios development and installed cordova 1.5.0 for phonegap.

Installation successfully done.

I followed the tutorial in [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS) site.

But it supports only for iPhone, How is it posible to create project for ipad in Cordova based application like Singleview based or like Empty application in xcode 4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the summary section of the target settings there is a dropdown with the options iPhone, iPad and universal.

However, that tutorial is rather out of date - for a new project you really should be using Cordova 2.2 at this point, which has an entirely different setup process.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS